# weceem 1.3-SNAPSHOT Provider net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory not found

Tags: grails, groovy, weceem

I cloned weceem-app, weceem-plugin and weceem-spring-security, build them all and I'm not able to start the app because of:

```
INFORMATION: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
Loading Weceem config from file:/Library/Tomcat/shared/classes/weceem.properties
Loaded weceem properties: [searchable:[index:[path:/Library/Tomcat/Websites/cms/search-indexes]]]
Setting searchable index path to: /Library/Tomcat/Websites/cms/search-indexes
Weceem: Initializing ehcache with default weceem ehcache.xml from plugin resource: class path resource [weceem-default-ehcache.xml]
2014-10-14 12:47:47,177 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  hibernate3.HibernatePluginSupport  - Set db generation strategy to 'update' for datasource DEFAULT
2014-10-14 12:47:47,287 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  hibernate4.HibernatePluginSupport  - Set db generation strategy to 'update' for datasource DEFAULT
2014-10-14 12:47:47,287 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR spring.BeanBuilder  - WARNING: Your cache provider is set to 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' in DataSource.groovy, however the class for this provider cannot be found.
Using Grails' default cache region factory: 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory'
```

even I add this dependency to weceem-app BuildConfig.groovy:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    compile "net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.6"
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to update weceem sources from GitHub (especially weceem-spring-security): probably that is the problem with hibernate plugin version, it was changed for weceem-spring-security to hibernate 3 usage. (I see in your log there is an INFO from hibernate4).

Comment: Hi July, thank you, now it works. I updated all the three projects.